# How to catch unknown error messages in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, automation, geckodriver

I am writing an automated login check in Python using Selenium with Firefox/geckodriver, which is triggered by a cron job every 15 minutes, for the purpose of making sure the login page is functioning correctly. The code checks several URLs in parallel using multiprocessing pool.

I am having difficulty catching and printing error messages when the type of error is unknown. When I do know the error, I can look for the text in the error message to catch it. But if I don't, how can I still check the error message element for visible text and then print whatever error it contains?

For errors that I already know exist, this approach is working:

```
            if success == False:  #if login unsuccessful

                print("checking for error message")
                try:
                    error_element = wait.until(cond.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='error-msg' and contains(text(),'Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again.')]")))

                    if error_element:
                        raise LoginError("Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again.")
                    

                except LoginError as e:
                    print("Error: ",e)

            else:
                print("NOTHING CAPTURED IN LOOP")
                break

    except Exception as error:
        attempts += 1
        err = error
        if attempts == 3:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(5)
            continue
```

'''